# Returning all repos under a given root path using GitPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gitpython

If I provide a root path such as ("C:/ProgramFiles") to the function,
the code should give a list, where each element is the

`(local path of this repo found under the root path, remote URL, remote repo name)`

requirements: a submodule is treated as a different repo with its master.

```
current solution algorithm:

repo = []
for each subfolder_any_depth in root:
  if gitpython(subfolder.path) not repo:
    continue
  if subfolder in repo:
    continue
  repo.append(subfolder)
```

Comment: I don't think GitPython alone has a function for this. You'll want to walk the directories *in* that path and, for each one, see if it represents a Git repository. If so, and if it might have checked-out submodules, keep walking *or* obtain the list of submodules at that point and stop the walk at that point (but don't do both).

Comment: so basically I need to walk into every subfolder no matter how deep?

Comment: When you do hit a Git repository, you can—at least potentially—take a shortcut, but otherwise, yes.